# Error subtracting values

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I have a problem with my subtraction the output should be

1 5 13 16 17  what >      1 5 13 16 17

4 8 3 1         I >        4 8  3 1

4 5 2       want   >           5 2 1

1 3         is the >            2 1

```
2           right side >             1
```

but as you can see its different output, can you tell me where im wrong and missing 
i just need some hints or tips. thanks in advance :)

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int input[10];
int dif[10];
int fin;

int dami;
int space;

int i;
int j;
int b = 0;


int main()
{
cout << "Enter up to 10 numbers,max 10:\n";
cin >> dami;
if (dami > 10)
{
    cout << "Input exceeds limit try again\n";
    system("pause");
    system("CLS");
    main();
}
else
{
    cout << "Input Test Case:\n";
    for (i = 0; i <dami; i++)
    {
        cin >> input[i];

        if (input[i] > 100000)
        {
            cout << "\nInput exceeds limit";
            system("pause");
            system("CLS");
            main();
        }
    }

    cout << "\n";
    for (int z = 0; z < dami; z++)
    {
        cout << input[z] << "  ";   
    }
/*  for (space = 0; space < dami - i; ++space)
    {

        cout << " ";
    }*/
    cout << "\n";
    for (i = 0; i < dami; i++)
    {

        for (j = i; j < dami -1;j++)
        {
            //subtraction part
            dif[j] = input[j+1] - input[j];

                fin = dif[j+1] - dif[j];

                if (fin < 0)
                {
                    fin = fin * -1;
                }

                cout << " " << fin;

        }

        cout << "\n";

    }
}
cout << "\n";
system("pause");

}
```

Comment: what does the debugger say

Comment: its compiling with no errors, what i meant was my output differs from the correct output which should subtract the previous set of subtracted numbers if i can post the picture you can get it easily

Comment: Calling `main` from `main` is BAD, mm'kay?

Comment: use the visual studio debugger to follow whats happening as the program runs

Comment: You also really don't need global variables.

Comment: http://i942.photobucket.com/albums/ad269/toling54/help2.png this should be the output

Comment: the only problem i got is in here   

dif[j] = input[j+1] - input[j];

                fin = dif[j+1] - dif[j];

Comment: @abelenky is right, recursive calls to main are not good.  See 5.2.2/9 of the standard http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3797.pdf. I recommend putting your recursive logic into a separate function just to clean it up a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, read your user input and if it is sane, place it into an array.

Then pass the input array and the number of elements it contains into a <s>recursive</s> function such as this:

```
void diff1(int items[], int count)
{
    if (count > 0)
    {
        for (int n=0; n<count; n++)
        {
            cout << items[n] << " ";
            items[n]=abs(items[n]-items[n+1]);
        }

        cout << "\n";
        diff1(items, --count);
    }
}
```

&Here is [a minimal implementation](http://ideone.com/bq8IyS) of the function.

*(nb: i'm sure you can figure out any fancy indentation you may require :p)*

Comment: btw: i suspect this is homework. if you were to use the `homework` tag you might avoid-down-votes/gain-sympathetic-interest ;)

Comment: its my homework but i didnt request directly for the answers, i just ask for what is wrong and for some tips :) and thankyou for your replies :)

Comment: sry:/ i hope i didn't spoil it for you. i use SO plenty & sometimes feel compelled to contribute something. tbh, i'm a bit ashamed i answered this..lol. but it vexed me that you received down-tics (some folk on here are more pointy!) ~you were so near yet sooo far. &really, the codes you posted needed to be totally nuked. (; in any case you got some good advice in the comments ;) ++fyi: forgot to provide [a non-recursive](http://ideone.com/QQBx09) alternative.